# Keep hovering state of parent element when hovering child element

Tags: html, css

my Menu is something like this:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
 <ul class="left">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-main-menu menu-item-cine-suntem has-dropdown not-click" id="menu-item-60"><a href="#">TopLevel Menu</a>
   <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-main-menu menu-item-misiuneviziune" id="menu-item-66"><a href="#">SubLevel Menu</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

And the CSS that ads a black arrow when I hover over the TopLevel Menu

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:hover:after{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: inset 5px;
        border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
        border-top-style: solid;
        margin-top: 22px;
        z-index:999;
      }
```

How do I get that arrow to stay visible, when I hover the child element of that menu item, because now as soon as I start hovering the child, the arrow from the parent item disappears.

Comment: I know that the above markup is missing some closing tags, on the website those tags are there.

Comment: The menu is located here : http://asptmr.studyor.net/ if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:hover:after{...}
.top-bar-section li a:hover, .top-bar-section .dropdown li a:hover{background:#c1212e;}
```

to

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown:hover > a:after {...}
.top-bar-section li:hover a, .top-bar-section .dropdown li:hover a{background:#c1212e;}
```

Note:

Closing tags are missing in your HTML markup. Which is a bad practice.

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nq87/1)

Comment: @user2997903 did you try my code? I changed in your site via inspect element. it is working.

Comment: thank you, the first time I tried it didn't work, but I tried again and took your code with copy paste and it's working fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the hover for `list-item` i.e `li:hover` to achieve what you are looking for, as that will select the parent to have the hover that is visible on hover only for the child elements.

***PS: Your above markup as provided is jagged and not correct. You need to correct it for the code to work properly.***